# How to deconstruct string data in python?

Tags: python, string, haversine

```
>>> st['xy'][0]
>>> '(35.25792753, 129.2127994)'
>>> filled['xy'][0]
>>> (37.77432579, 128.9071418)
```

I need ( x , y ) data format not '( x , y ) ' for using haversine function.

How do I deconstruct string data ?

Comment: Could you expand your code example? it is unclear where st and filled originate from and which haversine implementation you use.

Comment: What is the source of these strings? *That* is your fundamental problem. You should fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ast.ast_literal](https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval)

ast.literal provides safe construction of objects from strings (i.e. safer than eval)

```
import ast
value = ast.literal_eval(st['xy'][0])

# value becomes tuple: (35.25792753, 129.2127994)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is a string. If it is always of a format similar to the one shown you can do:

```py
data = st['xy'][0]
x, y = data.split(" ")
x, y = float(x[1:-1]), float(y[:-1])  # Slice parentheses and comma away
```

You can also use a regex (this method is more general):

```py
import re
data = st['xy'][0]
number_pattern = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)'
x, y = re.findall(number_pattern, data)  # NB: Will error out if your string is not well-formatted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in module, [re](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEz-Xbn-7pAhWsTN8KHStYACkQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fre.html&usg=AOvVaw3Rsq9kABRxR4gH08n-cRdW):

```
import re

t = tuple(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", st['xy'][0]))
```